# How do I put back de CKE image dialog box?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

On Drupal 8, I can't find [the image dialog box](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/image2) I used to have on Drupal 7.

I read this is a core issue, but my contributors are used to it and have a different level of expertise. This little dialog box allowed them to choose the size of the picture and to put the `<alt>` tag.

How can I put it back on Drupal 8, installing the CKE image2 plugin? Did I miss something? I can't find anything on the web of people complaining about the image dialog box suppression.